# Python3: Objects get created without attributes?

Tags: python, class, object

I have a representation of a street with traffic lights like this:

```
"...R............G......"
```

R, G and O represent Red, Green and Orange, everything else is just street. I am trying to calculate what color the traffic lights are after a certain amount of time.

I decided to create an array representing this street. The array will only contain "." representing the street, or traffic light objects.

```
color_sequence = ["G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "O", "R" ,"R" ,"R" ,"R" ,"R"]
class TrafficLight:
    def __init__(self, starting_color):
        if starting_color == "G":
            self.individual_offset = 0
        elif starting_color == "O":
            self.individual_offset = 5
        elif  starting_color == "O":
            self.individual_offset = 6

    def get_color(self, step):
        return color_sequence[(step + self.individual_offset)  % len(color_sequence)]
```

As you can see a traffic light object only holds its "offset". The offset is needed since all trafficlights follow the color_sequence but start at a different point in this sequence.

The get_color method then claculates what color the traffic light displays at a certain time and to return this value.

I construct the array containing the traffic lights from the original string like this:

```
def parse_road(road):
    road_with_working_trafficlights = []
    for element in road:
        if element == ".":
            road_with_working_trafficlights.append(element)
        else:
            road_with_working_trafficlights.append(TrafficLight(element))
    return road_with_working_trafficlights
```

My problem is, that the traffic_light objects seem to get created/instanciated without their individual_offset attribute. When I try to call the get_color method, I get an error, that the traffic_light object does not have an attribute individual_offset.

> return color_sequence[(time + self.individual_offset)  %
> len(color_sequence)] AttributeError: 'TrafficLight' object has no
> attribute 'individual_offset'

I am unable to find out why this happens.
If I create a traffic_light object like this

```
my_light = traffic_light("R")
```

there are no issues, vars(my_light) shows that my_light.individual_offset does exist and my_light.get_color() works as intented.

I am unsure why this is not the case when I create the traffic_light objects as shown in the parse_road function.

Is there an error in this function or in my class definition?

Comment: In your ``__init__``, you check twice for ``O`` and miss ``R``. You should add ``else: raise ValueError()`` at the end of the if-elif-chain to catch this kind of fallthrough.

Comment: Or just use `self.individual_offset = color_sequence.index(starting_color)`, which avoids the whole `if` statement and provides a `ValueError` if `starting_color` has an incorrect value.